# How do I recursively find key name in nested objects that contain an empty object?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I initially receive a response of

```
var o={
    "StudentInfo": [{
        "Name1": [{
            "100": {
                "a": "12"
            }
        }, {
            "101": {
                "a": "50"
            }
        }]
    }, {
        "Name2": [{
            "102": {}
        }, {
            "103": {
                "b": "50"
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

I have a JSON objects, after some operations, objects is empty(like empty objects 102), I want to print it and parent objects names (like "Name2").

I tried this,

```
    var emptyKeys = [];
    var FLAG=false;

    function emptyObjToNull(object,keysArr){
        var isObject, hasKeys, isArray, current;
        for(var k in object){
            if(!object.hasOwnProperty(k))
                return;
            current = object[k];
            console.log("current KK "+k);
             console.log(current);

            isObject = typeof current == 'object';
            hasKeys = isObject && Object.keys(current).length !== 0;
            if(hasKeys){
                emptyObjToNull(current, keysArr);
            }else if(isObject && !hasKeys){
               //object[k] = null; // Set the key directly, not the reference
               FLAG=true;
               keysArr.push(k);
            }
        }
    }

emptyObjToNull(o,emptyKeys);

console.log(emptyKeys);
```

Comment: could the structure be more nested?

Comment: you just want to find empty object right ?

Comment: if your initial object has fixed structure - no need to use recursion, just loop

Comment: no, It is not fixed structure. Yes , I want to find empty object and their parent key.  for example if 102 is empty i want to print "Name2" , If 101 and 102 is empty then i want to print "Name1" and "Name2"... respectively

Comment: @user3265033: the requirement in the comment above does not go hand in hand with the question's title. 102 is not an empty array, it's an empty object.

Comment: Yes @veverke.. its empty object. not array

Answer (score 0):

You can try recursion.

Note: this will not be very optimized and might throw error(*maximum stack size exceeded*) for big JSON with high nesting.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/hL4hgzwe/)

```js
var o={StudentInfo:[{Name1:[{100:{a:"12"},1000:{}},{101:{a:"50"}}]},{Name2:[{102:{}},{103:{b:"50"}}]}]};

function findEmptyObjects(obj, parent) {
  var result = [];
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    var _o = obj[key];
    if (Array.isArray(_o)) {
      _o.forEach(function(_item) {
        if (typeof(_item) === "object")
          result = result.concat(findEmptyObjects(_item, key))
      })
    } else if (typeof(_o) === "object") {
      if (isEmptyObject(_o)) {
        result.push({
          "object": key,
          "parent": (parent || "")
        })
      } else
        result = result.concat(findEmptyObjects(_o, key));
    }
  });
  return result;
}

function isEmptyObject(obj) {
  return typeof(obj) === "object" && Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}

var r = findEmptyObjects(o, undefined);
console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right this should do it:

```
function doitNow(obj, emptyKeys) {
  var ittr = [];

  if (isObject(obj))
    ittr = Object.keys(obj);

  ittr.forEach(function(key) {
    if (isObject(obj[key]) && Object.keys(obj[key]).length === 0) {
      emptyKeys.push(key);
      obj[key] = null;

      // Array or object will return true. No need for explicit check
    } else if (isObject(obj[key]))
      obj[key] = doitNow(obj[key], emptyKeys);
  });

  return obj;
}

function isObject(o) {
  return typeof o == 'object';
}
```

Essentially it will iterate an objects properties or an array looking for objects. If an object has no properties it will assign it null. I think thats what you wanted from the comment but it can be removed if not. It then pushes the empty objects key to the passed array. Finally it returns the object.

You don't have to treat arrays any different than objects once you have the keys. Arrays are just objects with numeric integer properties (and a special relationship with `.length`). We only check if its an array or object for the recursive call.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6tm6dxfz/6/)

Comment: You should first check for arrays. `typeof a` will also return `object`

Comment: @Rajesh actually that makes it even easier, the check is not needed. `Object.keys` on an array will return the numeric properties. Interesting never done that before. Don't know how i feel about whether you should or not. EDIT: looking at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) it appears to be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Then you should remove check for `Array.isArray`. Also check if `ittr` is of type array before looping. If ittr is something like `"a": "50"`, this will fail, since it does not have forEach function

Comment: @Rajesh Modified it, found a better way still.